# Как открыть внешний файл в Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

В программу должна была быть встроена кнопка ведущая на внешний ехе-шник. Есть
строковая переменная Path, которой я в начале присвоил текущий путь:

```
Path:=extractfilepath(paramstr(0));
```

С помощью этой переменной у меня браузер переключался между страницами.

```
if Node.StateIndex = 8 then
WebBrowser1.Navigate(Path+'kek\l5.htm');
```

Но когда я делаю то же самое с тем внешним ехе-шником, то это уже не работает. Вот я открываю внешний файл по нажатию кнопки:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ShellExecute(handle,'open','C:\Users\Пользователь1\Desktop\kekek\test.exe',nil,nil,SW_SHOW);
end;
```

Это работает только если я пишу полный путь, что естественно никуда не годится. Если я делаю вот так:

```
ShellExecute(handle,'open',Path+'test.exe',nil,nil,SW_SHOW);
```

То появляется ошибка [Error] Unit1.pas(292): Incompatible types: 'String' and 'PAnsiChar'.

Подскажите пожалуйста либо как починить этот код, либо какой-то другой способ открыть внешний файл.

Comment: попробуйте `PChar(Path+'test.exe')`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо большое!

Comment: @Grundy Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Данная WinApi функция принимает в качестве параметра указатель на строку и для литералов строк компилятор занимается приведением сам.

Но так как в данном случае передается не литерал строки, нужно привести его к нужному типу вручную

```
PChar(Path+'test.exe')
```